# Share Jenkins credentials across multiple TFS projects

Tags: jenkins, tfs

Is there a way to share Jenkins service endpoint credentials across multiple TFS projects? We have close to 30 projects, and each build requires us to configure the same set of credentials.

I would like to set an environment variable or something that would allow us to manage those credentials in one place for all TFS projects.

For a specific project, you click the gear here:

[image: Edit TFS Queue Jenkins Job with arrow pointing to gear]

And then enter the credentials here:

[image: TFS Jenkins service endpoint credential form]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible yet, there is a [Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365669/service-endpoints-should-be-global-across-all-proj.html) about it, you can up vote there.

To automate the process you can create the Jenkins endpoints with the Rest API [Endpoints - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create).

Answer (score 1):

No. Service connections are scoped at the Team Project level. Team Projects are intended to be largely isolated from one another, so there is limited ability to share things between them. If you need to manage a service endpoint across many projects, you'll need to look at the REST APIs and write a programmatic solution.